# Creating a middleman application between a website and a locally installed application

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm tasked with creating an application that simply passes information from a website (using javascript) to start an application on the local machine. So far I have tried two approaches but I am not exactly happy with them, they work fine but I want to know if there are any other approaches that would be more effective.
Here is what I have tried.

- Using a windows service: I have this working but because of the session 0 stuff that blocks services from directly interacting with applications on the users session I had to use a bit of a hack to get it working, Probably going to avoid doing this at all costs.
- Using an invisble console application that starts on windows startup, seems like the best thing so far but it just doesn't feel like the best way to go about this.

Is there anything better than these?

Points of note:

1. There will be a certain trigger on the website that will send a jquery post request to this "middleman" app.
2. The "middleman" app will be installed and running before the user is using the website

Comment: Why not have a normal app, minimized to tray?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder Yeah, Never thought of that. Seems like the best solution now thinking about it.

Comment: Your problem description is very unclear. "start an application on the local machine" - when should this be started, by what trigger? Is there a user sitting in front of the machine, why can he not just start your middleman application? Or are you trying to create something like a remote control?

Comment: @RichardMc Your question details are a bit confusing. Is the app on the client or on the server?

Comment: @AlexandruB On the Client.

Comment: @RichardMc, did you see my suggestion/answer? Can we wrap this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a normal app, minimized to tray? That way you can interact with it if you need to, but it's out of the way, doing its thing. Full access to what you need to do?

```
Private Sub myform_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        Me.ShowInTaskbar = False

        'show notification

        With myNotifyIcon
            .BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info
            .BalloonTipText = "Running, but hidden"
            .BalloonTipTitle = "Going going gone..."
            .ShowBalloonTip(3000)
        End With

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If using iis you can inject your code in its pipeline.
Other web servers must have the same logic